# Sending emails per line item in a repeating table

Tags: infopath, designer-workflow

Folks, I have one form that has a repeating table, two people picker fields that I want to send emails to when the conditions are met. My problem so far is the first email works, but if I Insert another item for the table, none of those emails go out. I've tried a number of ways to work around the problem but so far nothing is helping.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've been able to do something like that is with Nintex reading the repeating table XML and for each looping over each row. Out of the box, there isn't anything that you can do to meet that requirement. I believe you'll need to turn to an event receiver or other server side code to meet the need.

Comment: I was able to use count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1 to get a row number, then base my workflow off that plus a previous number field for my conditions.